# read from a .txt file in BATCH, without using literal path

Tags: batch-file, path

Basically, i would like to use the `type` command, but I can't provide the actual path.
Currently my attempt was

```
type "./TESTS/Test1.txt"
```

but I'm assuming that since it's a relative path, it can't work.
I've run into the same issue with `copy` and `xcopy`.

I have been unable to solve this issue or find anything online.
Is there way to do this?

EDIT:
To clarify, I am trying to get my .bat file, to read the contents of a .txt file located in a subfolder (meaning the subfolder and the .bat file are in the same folder), and print it to the console.

Comment: Commands need to know where to find the files to process. You can use relative paths, but there must be some absolute starting point. You need to be aware that the path to the script, the path to the current working directory and the path to the file to process are three different things. But first of all, you need to clarify your situation, because your current post is unclear, so it is hard to help you...

Comment: `./`, or correctly using Windows path separators `.\ `, is relative only to the current working directory, and with `cmd.exe` is completely unnecessary, `Type "TESTS\Test1.txt"` would function exactly the same. You need to explain better what you are hoping to achieve, because if you don't inform the interpreter of the name and, if necessary, its location, how do you expect it to know what to `Type`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've now edited your question but seemingly not provided feedback on my earlier comment, here it is as an answer.

Windows and it's command interpreter, `cmd.exe` uses the backslash **`\`** as its path separator.

Although many commands seem to accept the forward slash interchangeably, `Type` isn't one of those.

Additionally **`.\`** is relative only to the current working directory, and in `cmd.exe` is unnecessary, *though valid*.

The following should therefore work as you intended:

```dos
Type TESTS\Test1.txt
```

---

```dos
Type "TESTS\Test1.txt"
```

---

```dos
Type .\TESTS\Test1.txt
```

---

```dos
Type ".\TESTS\Test1.txt"
```

---

If the location you are using is being received in the batch file with the forward slashes, you could set it to a variable, then expand that variable substituting the forward slashes for backward slashes:

```dos
Set "Variable=./TESTS/Test1.txt"
Type "%Variable:/=\%"
```

---

It may be necessary, depending upon the code we cannot see, to navigate to the batch file directory first, *since it may not necessarily be the current working directory at the time of the invokation of those commands*.

To do that use:

```dos
CD /D "%~dp0"
```

Answer (score 0):

`%~dp0` provides the folder, where your batchfile resides (including the last `\`) (does of course only work inside a batch file). So:

```
type "%~dp0Test\test1.txt"
```

is exactly what you want: `<folder_where_my_batchfile_is\><subfolder_Test>\<File_test1.txt>`
independent of your "working folder" (where the batchfile might have `cd` or `pushd` to).

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it basically work by using `%CD%`? Like, `TYPE "%CD%/Subfolder/Test1.txt"`? `%CD%` is the windows variable for "Current Directory" and should be set to whatever directory the batch file is working in and since you're trying to access a folder within the same directory this should work. You're question is quite unclear, however, and I hope I'm not misinterpreting.